# Create array php and output option value

Tags: php, arrays, html-select, laravel-blade

I try to build a function which should create an array. This array I want to put out in my view.
This is the function, Im not sure how to build the array.

```
 public function getSpielplan(){
        //$newdata =  array (

        $spieltagSpiel = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();
            foreach($spieltagSpiel as $spieltagSpielOutput){

                $heimName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $spieltagSpielOutput->Heimmannschaft)->get();
                    foreach($heimName as $heimNameOutput){

                        $gastName = Verein::where('V_ID', '=', $heimNameOutput->Gastmannschaft)->get();
                            foreach($gastName as $gastNameOutput){

                                //array ($spieltagSpielOutput->Spielplan_ID, $heimNameOutput->Name, $gastNameOutput->Name)
                            }
                    }
            }
        //);
        //return view('spielplan')->with('alleSpiele', $newdata);
    }
```

In my view based on blade from laravel, this will be my output

```
div class="col-xs-6">
                label for="">Spielauswahl/label>
                select class="form-control input-sm" name="spiele" id="spiele">

                @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)     
                    option value="{!! HERE MUST BE SPIELPLAN_ID [array0?]!!}">{{HERE MUST BE NAME [array1?] }}/option>     
                @endforeach
                /select>
            /div>
```

In the value must be Spielplan_ID, I think must be the first column of the array [0]? And in the option array I need Name array [1]. What I have to change that this will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u need Spielplan_ID as option value, and option name should be combined with both heimName and gastName right? I consider that V_ID is the primary key of Verein model.  If I am right, then follow these codes.

```
public function getSpielplan(){

  $spieltagSpiel = Spielplan::where('Spieltag', '=', 1)->get();

  foreach($spieltagSpiel as $spieltagSpielOutput){

   $heimName=Verein:: where('V_ID','=',$spieltagSpielOutput->Heimmannschaft)->first();

   $gastName = Verein:: where('V_ID', '=', $heimNameOutput->Gastmannschaft)->first();

   $resultData[$spieltagSpielOutput->Spielplan_ID] =  $heimName->Name. $gastName->Name;

  }

   return view('spielplan')->with('alleSpiele', $resultData);

}
```

blade view should like this,

```
 @foreach( $alleSpiele as $alleSpieleKey => $alleSpieleName )
   <option value="{{ $alleSpieleKey }}">
   {{ $alleSpieleName }}
   </option>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

$alleSpiele is a collection of data object after iteration this object, you should use object name not array. You can try to change this part of code

```
@foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)         
  <option value="{{ $alleSpieleOutput->SPIELPLAN_ID }}">
   {{$alleSpieleOutput->Name }}
  </option>         
@endforeach
```